# Show data source(s) of child class in Telerik Reporting Visual Studio Data Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik-reporting

In the Visual Studio Telerik Reporting Designer, the Data Explorer pane shows all data sources and their members for drag-and-drop to the designer. We have reports that we are inheriting from a base report, however. In this case, the Data Explorer is showing the data source(s) of the base report (`objectDataSource.DataSource = typeof(BaseViewModel)`) rather than the child report (`objectDataSource.DataSource = typeof(ChildViewModel)`) that is currently open in the designer. Is there a way to get the Data Explorer to instead show the data sources of the child report?

Here is our relevant code:

```
public partial class BaseReport
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
        objectDataSource.DataMember = "GetRecords";
        objectDataSource.DataSource = typeof(BaseViewModel);
        objectDataSource.Name = "objectDataSource";
        DataSource = this.objectDataSource;
    }

    protected Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource objectDataSource;
}

public class BaseViewModel
{
    ...
    // without this dummy method, an exception is thrown in Data Explorer
    public IEnumerable<string> GetRecords()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
    ...
}

public partial class ChildReport : BaseReport
{
    public ChildReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objectDataSource.DataSource = typeof(ChildViewModel);
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<MyRecord> GetRecords()
    {
        return GetMyRecords();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, seems to be a known issue with the Designer.

> When the report inherits from a custom class instead of
>   Telerik.Reporting.Report you will lose the design-time support for
>   this report in the Visual Studio report designer. Thus, we recommend
>   to inherit from the default Telerik.Reporting.Report class while
>   designing and saving the report. Once you are done you can change the
>   inheritance to apply your custom class as a template.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/report-inheritance#pckM3wbuxESVkRVB3icPWA